# How to start the android emulator with my keystore file?

Tags: android

How to start the android emulator with my own keystore file? So that all the apps on the emulator will be having my keystore file.

Please advise me.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible.

Apps are signed at compile time, the signature cannot be altered afterwards.

Moreover, why would you need that.
It seems you have a major misunderstanding concerning keystores and app signatures on Android. Just google it.

Comment: I want to do the automation testing where I may access the different  native apps on the device. To access the other apps like settings/camera I dont have the access.If my application and the other apps has the same signature then only I can able to access the apps. If there is any way please let me know. Or else if i can able to get the keystore files to sign my app I can go ahead with my automation?